# Is it possible to find the dimensions of a file (PDF) using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to find the dimensions of a file (PDF) just before upload?

Comment: Javascript has no access to any information about files being uploaded.

Comment: The pages in a PDF file can have different dimensions.

Comment: Anyway, using [`pdf.js`](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/), a page of a PDF has what seems to be its dimensions in the `pageInfo.view` property: http://jsbin.com/EhiyiGo/1/. (I'm guessing indices `0` and `1` are a position, and `3` and `4` seem to be the dimensions. No idea which is which since their example PDF is a square.) I was only poking at their provided samples so I can't actually explain how that library works.

Comment: Also: the internal dimensions of a PDF file are "points", which is 1/72th of an inch. Seeing how PDF is a vector format, for rendering on-screen they can be considered more or less like an abstract unit that doesn't represent a useful physical size.

Comment: @Barmar The File API lets you read the file selected in an `<input type="file">`: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/